# Dagger Dependency Injection Provider with Qualifier

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I'd like to get a confirmation that: if two providers providing the same type of instance, one with qualifier and the other one without, would this work?

```
// Existing provider
@Singleton
@Provides
static MetricsCollectorFactory provideMetricsCollectorFactory(){}

// New one to be added
@Singleton
@Provides
@VersionBasedMetricsCollectorFactory
static MetricsCollectorFactory provideVersionBasedMetricsCollectorFactory(){}
```

For the following two cases, especially the TestClass1, will Dagger know which MetricsCollectorFactory to inject?

```
@Inject
TestClass1(MetricsCollectorFactory basicFactory)

@Inject
TestClass2(@VersionBasedMetricsCollectorFactory MetricsCollectorFactory basicFactory)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as on the [Dagger dev guide](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/#qualifiers), there are zero or one qualifier instances per key or binding, and absent is different than present.

However, from a readability perspective, you might consider avoiding letting the two coexist—particularly if your team is unfamiliar with Dagger. Your `@VersionBasedMetricsCollectorFactory MetricsCollectorFactory` might wind up as a field `metricsCollectorFactory`, which might cause an unfamiliar developer to inject a bare `MetricsCollectorFactory` instead of a desired `@VersionBasedMetricsCollectorFactory MetricsCollectorFactory`. In contrast, introducing an alternative like `@Default MetricsCollectorFactory` might be helpful, or at least would provide a useful compilation error to encourage a more careful reading of the injection key.